# Create Oracle CTXSYS.CTXCAT index with Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I'm trying to create an Oracle CTXSYS.CTXCAT index type with Liquibase. How can I create this type of Oracle index with Liquibase?

The way that I've performed the operation is with an SQL changeset

```
<changeSet id="1" author="giovanni.esposito">
    <sql endDelimiter="/">
        CREATE INDEX idx_full_txt_search ON ${defaultSchemaName}.employee(full_text_search) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT;
        /
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

When Liquibase executes the sentence it returns ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option. But, with SQLDeveloper I'm able to create the index with the same sentence.

**SOLUTION**

```
<changeSet id="1" author="giovanni.esposito">
    <sql endDelimiter=";">
        CREATE INDEX idx_full_txt_search ON ${defaultSchemaName}.employee(full_text_search) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Ok, for any that could be facing this problem. I found the error, the endDelimiter should be ';' and not '/'.
I'll edit the question adding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any that could be facing this problem. I found the error, the endDelimiter should be ';' and not '/'. I'll edit the question adding the solution.

SOLUTION

```
<changeSet id="1" author="giovanni.esposito">
    <sql endDelimiter=";">
        CREATE INDEX idx_full_txt_search ON ${defaultSchemaName}.employee(full_text_search) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```